# How to display Rails select field values rather than stored integers in other views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a select field in a Rails app that is NOT tied to a related model, but stores integer values for a static series of options , i.e.,

```
<%= select (:this_model, :this_field, [['Option1',1],['Option2',2],['Option3',3],['Option4',4]] ) %>
```

In a show/ index view, if I want to display the option text (i.e. Option1, Option2, etc) rather than the integer value stored in the database, how do I achieve this?

Thanks for helping a noob learn the ropes!

**EDIT**

Based on Thorsten's suggestion below, I implemented the following. But it is returning nil, and I can't figure out why.

Invoice model:

```
@@payment_status_data = { 1 => "Pending Invoice" , 2 => "Invoiced" , 3 => "Deposit Received", 4 => "Paid in Full"}

  def text_for_payment_status
     @@payment_status_data[payment_status]
  end
```

Invoice show view:

```
Payment Status: <%= @invoice.text_for_payment_status %>
```

In the console:

```
irb > i=Invoice.find(4)
=> [#<Invoice id: 4, payment_status: 1 >]
irb > i.text_for_payment_status
=> nil
```

I've tried defining the hash with and without quotes around the keys. What am I missing?

Comment: you could add `puts payment_status` in your text_for_payment_status method to see what value you get there. or just output i.payment_status in irb after the Invoice.find. Or just return @@payment_status_data instead of @@payment_status_data[payment_status]
 to see if the hash is properly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this would work:

```
<%= form_for @my_model_object do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :column_name "Some Description" %>
  <%= form.select :field_that_stores_id, options_for_select({"text1" => "key1", "text 2" => "key2"}) %>
<% end %>
```

**Update**

If you later want to display the text you can get it from a simple hash like this:

```
{"key1" => "text 1", "key2" => "text2"}[@my_object.field_that_stores_id]
```

But you better store this hash somewhere in a central place like the model.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord
  @@my_select_something_data = {"key1" => "text 1", "key2" => "text2"}
  def text_for_something_selectable
    @@my_select_something_data[field_that_stores_id]
  end
end
```

Then you can use it in your views like

```
@my_object.text_for_something_selectable
```

There are many possible variations of this. But this should work and you would have all information in a central place.

**Update**

Ok, I used something similar for our website. We need to store return_headers for rma. Those need to store a return reason as a code. Those codes are defined in an external MS SQL Server Database (with which the website exchanges lots of data, like orders, products, and much more). In the external db table are much more return reasons stored than I actually need, so I just took out a few of them. Still must make sure, the codes are correct.

So here goes he model:

```
class ReturnHeader < AciveRecord::Base
  @@return_reason_keys = {"010" => "Wrong Produc",
                          "DAM" => "Damaged",
                          "AMT" => "Wrong Amount"}

  def self.return_reason_select
    @@return_reason_keys.invert
  end

  def return_reason
    @@return_reason_keys[nav_return_reason_code]
  end
end
```

Model contains more code of course, but that's the part that matters. Relevant here is, that keys in the hash are strings, not symbols.

In the views i use it like this:

In the form for edit:

```
<%= form_for @return_header do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :nav_return_reason_code "Return Reason" %>
  <%= form.select :nav_return_reason_code, options_for_select(ReturnHeader.return_reason_select, @return_header.nav_return_reason_code) %>
<% end %>
```

(Maybe no the most elegant way to do it, but works. Don't know, why options_for_select expects a hash to be "text" => "key", but that's the reason, why above class level method returns the hash inverted.)

In my index action the return reason is listed in one of the columns. There I can get the value simply by

```
@return_headers.each do |rh|
    rh.return_reason
end
```

If you have trouble to get it run, check that keys a correct type and value. Maybe add some debug info with logger.info in the methods to see what actual data is used there.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, I need to display the result of your form on a show or index view. Hence this will be a static text field, rather than a form with select field. I'm looking for something similar to the way boolean values can be altered `<%= model.boolean_field? ? "Yes" : "No" %>`. Any ideas?

Comment: Great, this looks really promising! I've followed your example, but it's not returning any value at all, just blank space. I'm sure I've made a mistake somewhere. Where can I find out more about this, or what should I be searching for on Google?

Comment: @Andy Harvey: You could have used symbols for keys like :key1 instead of strings like "key1". your db most likely stores strings (or maybe you use simple ints, would be possible too). Wait a min, I have something similar in soe project and will put up a more elaborate example soon.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, I feel that this is really close, but my equivalent of rh.return_reason is still returning nil. I can't figure out why as my code follows yours, and I've tried all sensible permutations I can think of. My keys are stored as integers in the db. Any other ideas? I'm posting my code above.

Comment: I don't know why, but this is now working using my/ your original code. Possibly the result of a server restart? Who knows, but thank you, thank you, thank you!!

Comment: @Andy Harvey: server restart is quite possible a reason. adding class level variables may need a full reload here. And I enhanced the first solution I used until now a bit to make the answer look better, so my production code got a small enhancement too :)