# Rails 4 form: display database value in select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu

There are similar questions on Stack Overflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609835/rails-4-select-not-displaying-selected) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347479/how-to-display-rails-select-field-values-rather-than-stored-integers-in-other-vi), and I tried what the answers recommended, but I could not fix my problem.

I have a Rails form — **NOT** a simple_form form — with the following field in my new view:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :price, "Hourly Rate ($)" %><%= f.select :price, ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100'] %>
</div>
```

Then, I want to re-display this form in my edit view, with the value that was saved to the database, so I tried:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :price, "Hourly Rate ($)" %><%= f.select :price, ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100'], :selected => current_user.price %>
</div>
```

The problem is that the select field displays the first value instead of the one I am expecting.

—————

**UPDATE**: Following the answers given below, I implemented the following code:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :price, "Hourly Rate ($)" %>
  <%= f.select :price, [['10', '10'],['20','20'],['30','30'],['40','40'],['50','50'],['60','60'],['70','70'],['80','80'],['90','90'],['100','100']], selected: current_user.price, include_blank: 'Select your price' %>
</div>
```

It does not seem to work. Unless I made a mistake?

—————

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Is your form really bound to `current_user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two separate forms.

in **new.html.erb** and **edit.html.erb** put the following:

```
<%= render 'hourly_rate' %>
```

then in **_hourly_rate.html.erb** put the following:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :price, "Hourly Rate ($)" %>
  <%= f.select :price, options_for_select([['10',1], ['20',2], ['30',3], ['40',4], ['50',5], ['60',6], ['70',7], ['80',8], ['90',9], ['100',10]], @your_obj.price) %>
</div>
```

where `@your_obj.price` is something like 1, 2, 3...(or you can modify this to the actual prices if you'd prefer. You'd just need to change the arrays accordingly).

The `options_for_select` method is a helper whose second parameter allows you to pre-select an option by passing its value. For more on that, take a look at the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :price, "Hourly Rate ($)" %><%= f.select :price, [['10', '10'],['20','20'],['30','30'],['40','40'],['50','50'],['60','60'],['70','70'],['80','80'],['90','90'],['100','100']], selected: current_user.price, include_blank: 'Select your price' %>
</div>
```

you should pass an array of arrays which the left cell is the name and the right one is the value, then pass in selected by value and not by name, you should use this also in the first form:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :price, "Hourly Rate ($)" %><%= f.select :price, [['10', '10'],['20','20'],['30','30'],['40','40'],['50','50'],['60','60'],['70','70'],['80','80'],['90','90'],['100','100']] %>
</div>
```